# pom.xml in IntelliJ crossed out

Tags: pom.xml

I have created new module under java project, but the pom.xml under new module is crossed out. Tried re-creating new module and copy past of existing module didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Found the answer, From intellij go to settings → Build,Execution,Deployment → Build Tools → Maven → Ignored Files -> just uncheck the pom.xml file which is selected.

Reference -> https://markus-springer.medium.com/intellij-pom-xml-crossed-out-cant-build-project-module-3768c88b6eb2